# USB password prompt on plug-in

Tags: usb, security, windows-server-2008, group-policy

I want to create a security feature in Windows 7/XP, where if any random person plugs in his USB, it'll ask for the admin(or any other) password. This security is implemented at a very low level, where the USB device can't read/write unless password is provided.

I've seen this implemented using Group Policy with Windows Serve, but any other method will also do.

P.S: I want to implement this on Windows XP/7, Not Server editions.

Answer (score 0):

You can block USB ports through Group Policy for Users.

Note that if they have admin credentials, while Group policy can still block them, it can be blocked by installing a simple program that blocks Group Policy updates from the DC.

There are a few programs out there though that will provide you your password prompt.  A quick google brings up [MyUSBOnly.](http://widbox.com/ext/y5mwh)